# ZeroMQ Request/Reply does not reply in one direction

Tags: c, network-programming, zeromq

I use ZeroMQ's C interface to distribute computation among several machines. Locally, everything works as expected with `tcp://localhost:5555`. However, when running client and server on two machines A and B, the request and reply only works when the server is running on A and client is running on B. If it's the other way around, only the request is received on B and the client on A never receives the reply.

To verify, that I setup everything correctly, I compiled the first [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Ask-and-Ye-Shall-Receive) from the ZeroMQ guide but there is the same problem.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by two incompatible versions of 0MQ.

This is a known problem with 0MQ v3.0.x, 3.1.x, 3.2.0, 3.2.1. These versions all used an undocumented, incompatible version of the protocol (with no version number, so very hard to get interoperating), which was finally fixed in 3.2.2 stable. If you're running the older version, and this may have come with the language binding you're using, upgrade it. If there are serious reasons why you cannot upgrade, e.g. you have clients in the wild who are using the older versions, ask on the zeromq-dev list, someone may be able to help. For what it's worth, the protocol now has version numbers, and is backwards compatible with previous stable releases (2.2 and 2.1).

Comment: Incidentally, this question is on the FAQ: http://www.zeromq.org/area:faq#toc6 (I just added the part about request-reply)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed 3.2.2 from source on all machines and it works alright.